# PyCharm Editing - Delete the first 4 characters of every line in a code block?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, edit

I've found that I paste a lot of blocks (like below) to play around with in PyCharm. Is there a way to quickly delete the first 4 character's in each line versus manually doing so one by one?

**Before Example:**

```
1| def average_evens(start, end):
2|     sum = 0
3|     count = 0
4|     for i in range(start, end + 1):
5|         [fill in this blank] 
6|     return sum / count
```

**After Example:**

```
def average_evens(start, end):
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        [fill in this blank]
    return sum / count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add multiple carets (alt+mouse1 by default), then delete the characters, it's slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm has a [plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-product-as-the-vim-editor.html) that can be enabled to emulate Vim commands. With this enabled, you can press `<Ctrl>+v` to select blocks of text with the cursor. Starting with the cursor at the first character of the first line in your example, you could do

1. `<Ctrl>+v` (Enter visual block mode)
2. `5+<↓>` (Highlight 5 lines down)
3. `3+<→>` (Highlight 3 characters to the right, does this for all highlighted rows)
4. `x` (Delete the highlighted block)
   4a. `u` (Undo if you made a mistake)

The same instructions would work for any block you wanted to delete; you would just need to change the numbers in steps 2 and 3.